# Workaround the snapshot isolation in a writable CTE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, cte

The postgres docs [say](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html):

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), **so they cannot "see" each others' effects on the target tables**. This … means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query.

I'm looking for a way to work around this effect in a situation like this:

**Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1(id serial);

create table t2(id integer);

create function f1() returns integer language sql as $$
  insert into t1 default values returning id; --
$$;

create function f2() returns integer language sql as $$
  with w as (insert into t1 default values returning id)
  insert into t2(id) select id from w join t1 using(id) returning id; --
$$;
```

**Example**:

```
select f2()
/*
|     F2 |
----------
| (null) |
*/

select * from t1
/*
| ID |
------
|  1 |
*/

select * from t2
/*
| ID |
------
*/
```

<sub>*[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f34ba/1)*</sub>

I'd like the `insert` in `f2` to see the data in `t1` and so end up with 1 row in `t2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you return * from the CTE then you are effectively reading the row that you are currently trying to read from t1 -- that's how you mange to read the changes you're making to t1.

In your current code the join to t1 is redundant by the way, but I get the impression that you're using an example more simple than you really want.